# Boot time scheduled tasks using network resources

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

I'm setting up a single shared directory accessible to multiple servers for resources used during various scripts, \servers\share.

This directory is used for scripts including some that are scheduled using the "At system startup" trigger with the action of "\server\share\runme.exe".

This inherently fails since this directory isn't yet available, usually with the error code 2147942431, 0x8007001f, ERROR_UNHANDLED_ERROR.

Is there any quick and dirty method available to require scheduled tasks to have network connectivity before they start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any quick and dirty method available to require scheduled
>   tasks to have network connectivity before they start?

If it truly is that the network isn't available, then yes.  In the `Conditions` tab on the task at the bottom check the `Start only if the following network connection is available` and choose the NIC that is responsible for connectivity to those resources:

[image]

Comment: Great idea. I wish it were that simple. Several of the tasks are created dynamically by third parties and there isn't (?) a good way for me to set that option.

Comment: Dynamically with task scheduler and then a reboot kicks off?  Not sure what you mean, do you have an example with workflow?

Comment: The job runs - say a software update - reboots and automatically goes out and pulls the configuration down.

Comment: you checked this as the answer, did it work for you ok?  Or did you find the answer based on this answer?

Comment: This is the closest I think I'll be able to come. It handles most of the cases I need to deal with. In the others I'm guessing that I'll just need to pull down the files and work locally.

Answer (score 1):

The \server\share must be available to Guest (ie, unauthenticated users) - because "Startup" tasks run as Local System. This has to be allowed via both Share permissions and NTFS permissions, of course.

Alternatively, you could distribute and run a BAT file that puts a "net use" statement before running the remote EXE, but then you're putting a plaintext password in a file. Not secure, so probably don't do that.

Comment: I'm already set up that way; everyone and / or Domain Computers has access to scripts. They run under the SYSTEM context of my other hosts. I'm thinking that the network connection isn't up yet when the scheduled task tries to run.